# Unable to connect to instance of SQL Express following Asp.net MVC tutorial

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ssms

I am having trouble trying to switch over from using a LocalDb to using an instance of SQL express in Microsoft SQL Server. The following is my connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=.\MSSQLSERVER; Database=MvcDemo; Trusted_Connection=true; multipleActiveResultSets=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Along with the error message:[Error Message on SQL Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfqPi.png). Here is the picture of the Service name: [SQL Server Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1G2s.png).

Comment: This is irrelevant to asp.net MVC, It seems your credential for MS SQL management studio is incorrect. Always first, connect with SQL management to check the DB connectivity, then create a connection string in application

Comment: Have you tried `Initial Catalog=MvcDemo;` instead of `Database=MvcDemo;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to connect by changing the server name to the name of my laptop, everything else in the connectionString stays the same. If on windows go to windows start menu -> View your pc name. In other tutorials I have seen people using server instance names as well by checking the name of their SQL server instance under services.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationDbContext" 
         connectionString="Server=Name_Of_PC; Initial Catalog=MvcDemo; Trusted_Connection=true; multipleActiveResultSets=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,
I assume your dbcontext class name is "ApplicationDbContext".

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationDbContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=MvcDemo; Trusted_Connection=true; multipleActiveResultSets=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

You can also get the Server Explorer window to give you the connection string for the database being viewed, by right clicking on the database node and then on Modify Connection. Click Advanced and the connection string value will be displayed under the Data Source value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't give your Windows account access to the database. In SMMS, go down to the menu item highlighted in yellow. Right click on logins, select "New Login" and fill out the form, selecting windows authentication.

Then go to the database, MvcDemo/Security/Users (shown by the red arrow). Right click and add "New User". Select "Windows User" from the drop down and select yourself.

[image]